# Работа с SQLite android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Создаю Бд, вроде все правильно:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private final String LOG = "####MY_DB_LOG####";

    public static final String TABLE = "mytable";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID= "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";

    private String CreateTable = "create table " +TABLE + " ( "
            + COLUMN_ID +" integer primary key autoincrement,"
            +  COLUMN_NAME +" text, "
            + COLUMN_EMAIL +" text " + ")";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "myDb", null, 1);
        Log.d(LOG, "create database");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        Log.d(LOG, "create table");

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CreateTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Но  когда я пытаюсь сделать какую-то запись или другое действие - выбрасывает ошибку, что не существует колонки "email":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если комментировать все где используется данная колонка - работает!

**Подскажите, пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема ?**

Comment: Попробуйте очистить ресурсы приложения. Водможно у вас старая версия БД без сей колонки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не дало результатов ( та же ошибка!

Comment: лишние пробелы уберите. В частности - перед последней закрывающей скобкой. Да и после первой можно

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich, спасибо!! Проблему решил!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо Вам,за отзыв, но проблема была в моей невнимательности. И в том, что я делал по руководству в интернете, и там тоже была ошибка, но даже не обратил на нее внимание !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка спряталась, там где ее даже не искал!!!

В конструкторе класса - наследника от  SQLiteOpenHelper, *я не задаю расширение БД*, а только ее название! то есть:

```
 public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "myDb", null, 1);
    }
```

Исправив на:

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, "myDb.db", null, 1);
        }
```

**Все заработало!)**