# Создание и использование 2-х таблиц в базе данных на android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

пишу программу и хочу использовать базу данных, содержащую 2 таблицы(пока друг от друга не зависящие). 
Создал следующий класс для базы данных:

```
package example.englishapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE EnglishWords (" +
                "_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "word TEXT NOT NULL," +
                "translations TEXT NOT NULL," +
                "transcription TEXT NOT NULL," +
                "completed INTEGER" +
                ");");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ErrorsHelp (" +
                "_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "allWords INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                "learned INTEGER," +
                "leftToLearn INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                "forRepetition INTEGER," +
                "newError INTEGER," +
                "today INTEGER" + ");");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

Инициализирую БД в методе onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MY_SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        if (!hasVisited) {
            writeFile();
            readFile();

            startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstStartActivity.class));

            SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
            e.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
            e.commit();
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ct1 = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.cl1);

        btnSound = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSound);
        btnMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);

        tvLearningWords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLearningWords);
        tvTranscription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTranscription);

        setTitle("Новые слова");

        btnAnswer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer1);
        btnAnswer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer2);
        btnAnswer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer3);
        btnAnswer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer4);
        btnAnswer5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer5);

        for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
            completedWords.add(0);}

        btnSound.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnswer1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnswer2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnswer3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnswer4.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnAnswer5.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            createOldSoundPool();
        } else {
            createNewSoundPool();
        }

        mAssetManager = getAssets();

        theSound = loadSound("the.ogg");
        aboutSound = loadSound("about.ogg");
        position=0;

        if (hasVisited) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "position " + position);
            getNewWords(position);
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
```

Далее пытаюсь заполнить таблицы данными:

```
void readFile() {
        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(FILENAME)));
            String str = "";

            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, str);
                String[] strings = str.split("\t");
                word = strings[0];
                transcription = strings[1];
                translations = strings[2];
                completed = 0;

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("word", word);
                cv.put("transcription", transcription);
                cv.put("translations", translations);
                cv.put("completed", completed);

                mDb = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                long rowID = mDb.insert("EnglishWords", null, cv);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);

            }

                allWords = 500;
                learned = 0;
                leftToLear = 500;
                forRepetition = 0;
                newError = 0;
                today = dayat;


                ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();
                cv1.put("allWords", allWords);
                cv1.put("learned",learned);
                cv1.put("leftToLear",leftToLear);
                cv1.put("forRepetition",forRepetition);
                cv1.put("newError", newError);
                cv1.put("today",today);

                long rowID1 = mDb.insert("ErrorsHelp", null, cv1);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID1);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Всё проходит вроде-бы без ошибок, однако по логам ведётся запись в ячейку с ID = -1(при записи в таблицу ErrorsHelp)

```
08-10 22:45:31.338 29609-29609/tmp.engapp D/myLogs: row inserted, ID = -1
```

И соответственно при попытке взять из таблицы ErrorsHelp данные выскакивает ошибка:

```
08-10 22:47:58.888 29609-29609/tmp.engapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tmp.engapp, PID: 29609
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tmp.engapp/example.englishapp.StatisticActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
        at example.englishapp.StatisticActivity.onCreate(StatisticActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)*
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)*
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)*
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)*
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)*
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)*
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)*
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)*
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)*
08-10 22:47:58.908 850-30136/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
    ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
    sys.mobilecare.preload = false
08-10 22:48:02.228 30147-30147/? E/Zygote: v2
08-10 22:48:02.238 30147-30147/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
```

Данные пытаюсь получить из базы в другом activity:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class StatisticActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mInfo;
    SQLiteDatabase mInfoBase;

    TextView tvAllWord, tvProgressWord, tvProgressWordInt, tvLeftWord, tvLeftWordInt, tvLearning, tvLearningInt, tv, tvInt, tvToday, tvNewWord, tvNewWordInt, tvErrors, tvErrorsInt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistic);

        tvAllWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAllWord);
        tvProgressWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvProgressWord);
        tvProgressWordInt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvProgressWordInt);
        tvLeftWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLeftWord);
        tvLeftWordInt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLeftWordInt);
        tvLearning = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLearning);
        tvLearningInt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLearningInt);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tvInt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvInt);
        tvToday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvToday);
        tvNewWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNewWord);
        tvNewWordInt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNewWordInt);
        tvErrors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvErrors);
        tvErrorsInt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvErrorsInt);

        mInfo = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mInfoBase = mInfo.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mInfoBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ErrorsHelp", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        tvProgressWordInt.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        tvLeftWordInt.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        tvLearningInt.setText(cursor.getString(3));
        tvInt.setText(cursor.getString(4));
        tvNewWordInt.setText(cursor.getString(5));
        tvErrorsInt.setText(cursor.getString(6));
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать в чем заключается моя ошибка.

Comment: `row inserted, ID = -1` - означает, что запись не добавлена.

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/502110/11515 - возможно у Вас та же беда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из пустой таблицы возвращается пустой курсор, из пустого курсора нельзя получить данные. Нужно делать поверку курсора:

```
if (cursor != null // возможно и такое 
       && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    tvProgressWordInt.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    tvLeftWordInt.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    tvLearningInt.setText(cursor.getString(3));
    tvInt.setText(cursor.getString(4));
    tvNewWordInt.setText(cursor.getString(5));
    tvErrorsInt.setText(cursor.getString(6));
} else {
    // таблица пустая
    // как-то обрабатываем этот случай
}
```

Comment: я понял, что запись не происходит при id=-1, а в чем может быть ошибка? что я сделал не так? все поля, содержащиеся в таблице ErrorsHelp я инициализировал, и вызвал метод insert в readFile() саму базу открыл для записи...

Comment: Во второй лог добавьте что это именно ErrorsHelp - мне думается, что до него код не доходит. Вообще так на вскидку не скажешь, явных ошибок не видно - нужно обложить всё логами, пройтись дебаггером, посмотреть что с базой, что с таблицами, что с файлами, что читается, что пишется. И в первую очередь посмотрите нет ли в логах `IOException` или `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Ошибка была достаточно примитивной. Как оказалось, я неправильно выбрал имя для поля, которое вставлял, пересмотрел логи еще раз и обнаружил это. Спасибо)))